# Getting error of eclipse.idReplacer on automated build script

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am novice in eclipse PDE.
I created the feature project in eclipse. using pde tool, i created a build.xml.
When i run from eclipse, it runs fine, but when i run it from outside (terminal using `plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v20120321-1730/bin/./ant -verbose -debug -buildfile build.xml`
) I am getting error

```
Problem: failed to create task or type eclipse.idReplacer
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Also, from eclipse if another ant script calls my feature's build.xml, I am getting same exception.

I read the eclipse blogs, It seem bug is fixed, and Andrew Niefer's solution not working in my case. I also tried to download org.eclipse.releng.eclipsebuilder from its cvs and git, but i failed to download them.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

My configuration, 
java version "1.7.0_09", 
Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment Version: 3.6.2.r362_v20110203-7b7mFL2FET3dhHalh1iNZtL
Build id: M20110210-1200

Fedora14-64bit

Answer (score 1):

**Cause: The name is undefined. means the ANT task eclipse.idReplacer is not known**

Because you are running Ant outside Eclipse, the certain ANT 'task' names are undefined.  (For reference, 'eclipse.idReplacer' is defined in the Java class: org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.tasks.IdReplaceTask in file /lib/pdebuild-antsrc/org/eclipse/pde/internal/build/tasks/IdReplaceTask.java in the .../eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.2.v20121114-140810/lib/pdebuild-ant.jar Eclipse plugin (on my system) -- That java class implements IdReplaceTask class which extends the Task class, which is used to implement extensions to Ant.)

The problem is that the standalone Ant doesn't know about the eclipse.idReplacer.  Add an Ant 'typedef' tag to your build.xml to tell Ant that the new 'eclipse.idReplacer' task name is defined by ...IdReplaceTask.class

```
  <typedef name="eclipse.idReplacer"
     classname="org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.tasks.IdReplaceTask"/>
```

Tell Ant where to find the ...IdReplaceTask.class by adding a '-lib' option in the Ant command line:

```
ant -f /mydir/moredir/build.xml -lib \app\androidDev\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.2.v20121114-1 clean build.update.jar
```

The key thing in the command above is the '-lib ...' option that tells Ant where to find the jar that ...IdReplaceTask is defined in.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to import the jar(ant-contrib-1.0b3 which you can download and keep in eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20090120-1145/lib) in Eclipse, by Windows--?Preferences-->Ant-->Runtime--->Add External Jars in Ant Home Entries.

Could you let us see the build.xml file

Comment: Thanks Leo, Unfortunately because of companies policy I can not disclose code.